# matrix in R to compute degree of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

i would like to compute the degree of each vertex in the adjacency matrix,i have tried the following code in R:\

```
b=matrix(c(0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0),nrow=3,ncol=3)

for(i in 3){
  for(j in 3){
 v[i]<-sum(b[i,j])
   }
 }
```

but it did not give me the right value for each vertex

i want to get

```
 v[1]=2, v[2]=2 and v[3]=2
```

Can someone help me please

Comment: Would `colSums(b)` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do `colSums`

```
colSums(b)
#[1] 2 2 2
```